# Blender 2.6.1 export to ogre

Tags: blender, ogre

I'm using Blender v.2.6.1: is there a way to export my project (.blend) to .mesh and .skeleton?

I've tried to download BlenderExport and copy the script and all subdirectories either into ".blender/scripts", but when I open my .blend, in File->Export don't appear nothing to export in ogre files!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blender includes export script for a lot of formats, but you need to activate the scripts in the Files -> Preferences -> Add-on menu.

[Blender2Ogre](http://code.google.com/p/blender2ogre/) can export .scene, .mesh, .material, .skeleton.

Just follow the installation steps and tutorials.

Comment: I've just tried this: I've activated the Add-on but the exporter produces only .scene file (and not .mesh & .skeleton)...

Comment: You can try this exporter : [blender2ogre](http://code.google.com/p/blender2ogre/). I think it can export mesh and skeleton to ogre.

Comment: Ok, with this exporter everything works great! thank you!